# How free memory after of realloc

Tags: c

Is correct ways to free up memory in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ){

    char *string1, *string2;
    string1 = (char*) malloc(16);

    strcpy(string1, "0123456789AB");

    string2 = realloc(string1, 8);

    printf("string1 Valor: %p [%s]\n", string1, string1);
    printf("string2 Valor: %p [%s]\n", string2, string2);

    free(string1);
    free(string2);
    return 0;
}
```

Since the two pointers point to the same direction

Comment: A good sanity check is to count the number of times `malloc` is called, and the number of times `free` is called. These counts should be equal. This is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for your code being good. (special cases: `strdup` counts as +1 `malloc`; `realloc` counts as +1-1 or 0)

Comment: Also, treating the memory returned from `string2 = realloc(string1, 8);` as a NUL-terminated string causes undefined behavior, since your original `string1` is longer than 8 characters.  You can't truncate a C string that way and expect it to remain a string.

Comment: You also don't have to cast the result of `malloc`, the same way you use `realloc`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the (uninspired) expression "free pointers" (you used in your post, but edited it out since). You **don't free pointers**. You **free memory**. The pointer is just *telling* which memory.

---

In your example you have: the memory obtained from `malloc`. `string1` points to this memory. Then when you call `realloc` a new memory block is obtained (possibly starting at the same address, possibly not), but `realloc` takes care to release the old one if needed (and is therefore undefined behavior to access or free it yourself). `string2` points to this new memory block.

So you have to `free` just the memory block obtained from `realloc`. `string2` points to that memory.

Answer (score 8):

In short, no.

Per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **7.22.3.5  The `realloc` function**
>
> ...
>
> The `realloc` function  **deallocates  the  old  object  pointed  to 
>   by `ptr` and  returns  a pointer  to  a  new  object**  that  has  the
>   size  specified  by `size`.  The  contents  of  the  new object shall
>   be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the
>   lesser of the new and old sizes.  Any bytes in the new object beyond
>   the size of the old object have indeterminate values.

Once you call `realloc()`, you do not have to `free()` the memory addressed by pointer passed *to* `realloc()` - you have to `free()` the memory addressed by the pointer `realloc()` returns. (Unless `realloc()` returns `NULL`, in which case the *original* block of memory - passed *to* `realloc()` - has to be `free()`'d.)

Answer (score 3):

When you call `realloc`, either the returned pointer is the same as the original, or a new pointer is returned and the original pointer becomes invalid.  In the first case, calling `free` on both `string1` and `string2` results in a double-free since the pointers are equal.  In the second case, calling `free` on `string1` is a double-free since it was already freed.

So either way you have a double-free which results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From the man page for [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc):

> ```
> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
> ```
>
> The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes. The contents will be unchanged in the range
>   from the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new
>   sizes. If the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory
>   will not be initialized. If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent
>   to malloc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and
>   ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr). Unless ptr
>   is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(),
>   calloc() or realloc(). **If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr)
>   is done.**
>
> The realloc() function returns a pointer to the newly allocated
>   memory, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable **and may be
>   different from ptr**, or NULL if the request fails.

Also from the man page for [free](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free):

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which
>   must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or
>   realloc(). Otherwise, or **if free(ptr) has already been called before,
>   undefined behavior occurs**. If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

You only need to `free(string2)`.

Comment: Might be worth noting that if realloc returns NULL then the original pointer remains valid and must be free'd

Comment: *may* be different. But if it isn't the behavior is well defined. The lesson, I think, is to add sanity checks.

Comment: @Trey Your [comment](if (!printlines(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "urls.txt")) {) applies often, but not necessarily in the corner case of `realloc(string1, 0)` as it may return `NULL` and the the original pointer is free'd.

Answer (score 1):

The realloc implicity frees the input, it may not do anything at all, but you cannot free it after to re-alloced memory.  So

```
char *string1, *string2;
string1 = (char*) malloc(16);
....
string2 = realloc(string1, 8);  // this line implicitly frees string1

free(string1); // this is wrong !!!
free(string2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: in your code, calling `free(string2)` is correct, and sufficient.  Calling `free(string1)` is incorrect.

When you called `realloc` (and assuming that the call succeeded), its return value (which you stored in `string2`) became the one and only way to refer to the one block of memory that you have.

It may be that `realloc` resized your memory block "in place", meaning that the values of `string2` and `string1` are equal.  In that case, calling `free(string1)` is wrong because you're freeing the same pointer twice.

It may be that `realloc` moved your data to a new place in the process of resizing it.  In that case, the values of `string2` and `string1` are unequal.  But in that case, after it finds a new place for your data and copies it there, *`realloc` automatically frees the old block for you*.  So, again, calling `free(string1)` is wrong because you're freeing an already-freed pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `realloc` as something equivalent to:

```
void *
realloc(void *old, size_t new_size)
{
    size_t old_size = magic_internal_function_that_knows_the_size_of(old);
    void *new = malloc(new_size);
    if (new == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memcpy(new, old, new_size > old_size ? old_size : new_size);
    free(old);
    return new;
}
```

If you have the magic function that can figure out how big an allocation is from the pointer, you can implement `realloc` yourself like this. `malloc` pretty much must have this function internally for `free` to work.

`realloc` can also do clever things like figuring out that you're reallocating to a smaller size and just free part of your allocation or figure out that you're growing your allocation and there's enough space after to fit it. But you don't need to think about those cases. Thinking that `realloc` is malloc+memcpy+free will not mislead you except that you need to remember that `realloc` failing and returning NULL means it didn't do the `free`.